# No resource found error for `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.5.0` in android studio 1.3

Tags: android, android-studio, admob, google-play-services

I'm using [admob native ads example](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/tree/master/admob/NativeExample) for showing native ads like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29232122/1576416).
But when i have imported [this](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/tree/master/admob/NativeExample) project in Android Studio 1.3, I'm getting the following error.

```
E:\Shared_Folder\Sample Projects and Libraries\googleads-mobile-android-examples-master\admob\NativeExample\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-base\7.5.0\res\drawable\common_signin_btn_icon_light.xml

Error:(10, 28) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/common_signin_btn_icon_disabled_focus_light').

E:\Shared_Folder\Sample Projects and Libraries\googleads-mobile-android-examples-master\admob\NativeExample\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-base\7.5.0\res\drawable\common_signin_btn_text_light.xml

Error:(10, 28) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/common_signin_btn_text_disabled_focus_light').

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'D:\ANDROID-DEV\AndroidStudioSDK\build-tools\22.0.0\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

[image]

> I'm currently using beta version `1.3 Beta (June 18th, 2015)` of Android Studio. I have also checked it with stable version `1.2.2 Stable` of Android Studio. Issue still persists.

While using this sample app for admob native example, above error is showing. 
I'm unable to edit the resource as well. It says `Files under the build folder are generated and should not be edited`

What can be the solution for this?

I have used latest version of play services ads 7.5.0.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.5.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.5.0'
```

Please help to resolve this problem.

I have also reported this issue on [github](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/issues/17).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Answer](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/issues/17#issuecomment-158924959)

I was able to fix it using only this:

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0'

instead of this :

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.8.0'

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Update your Google Play services and Google Repository. It will works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue though I have updated play service libraries.
And I was able to fix by changing the dependency library order list. I kept play service libraries at the top in the dependency list.
Hope this helps.