# how to Implement admob native ads in android studio project?

Tags: admob, native-ads

I'm trying to implement native ads in my android application. But I want to do it using admob only. I searched a lot for solution but could not find exact one to do so.

Comment: i want simple and easy way to do this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implementing native ads in android using Admob? is it possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29232122/implementing-native-ads-in-android-using-admob-is-it-possible)

Answer (score 0):

Tooleap Ads is a simple and easy easy way to do this

Instead of requiring you to use the traditional listView adapter and showing the ad inside you content, they are showing admob native ads as a small floating bubble. When pressing on it you can see the full native ad.

Tooleap allows you to mediate other native ads networks, among them is Admob.

Here is an example of using their SDK inside your `activity` class:

```
BubbleImageAd = new BubbleImageAd(this);
bubbleImageAd.setAdUnitId("YOUR_AD_UNIT_ID");
bubbleImageAd.loadAndShowAd(this);
```

You can check them out [here](http://www.tooleap.com/ads).

[image]
[image]